# What happened at the end of Tokyo Ghoul?

Tags: tokyo-ghoul

I am a bit confused by Tokyo Ghoul season 2's ending. Why was Hide bitten, and by who or what? Was it in that "war"? Or did Kaneki bite him?

And why did Yomo stop Touka when she was running to Kaneki (it was at the moment when he was carrying Hide)? Was it just because he did not wanted to let her be killed? Or was it something deeper?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sadly, anime sacrifices a lots of plot details from manga in sake of 12ep seasons, so numerous things are just not explained. I've abandoned anime at around half of first season, so I will reference manga as explanation.

In a nutshell, main reason why Yomo stopped Touka was because he didn't wanted her to be killed indeed. He referenced this as "his last job in Anteiku". From all the talking of Yomo in manga Ch. 130, I assume, that main reason for Touka to say alive is that she can keep helping ghouls, who has lost their way in life, just like Anteiku crew were doing before.

Regarding Hide, it was heavily implied in chapters 136-137 of original manga, that Kaneki ate him. But Hide offered this by himself, since he knew that Arima is awaiting for Kaneki (and Kaneki was unable to resist his hunger, since he was in half-kakuja form). Maybe, in anime adaptation, events are slightly different, but outcome is same - Hide sacrificed his life to feed Kaneki, so Kaneki can heal his wounds and restore his power.

Answer (score 2):

In the anime, Takizawa's ending is death by Noro. Hide witnesses that, and gasps, alerting Noro's attention to him. When we next see Hide, he is wounded, meaning Noro attacked him. Unlike the manga, Kaneki had nothing to do with Hide's wounds.

Yomo stopped Touka mostly out of paternal feeling(he is her uncle) but it is a well know fact that Kaneki has severe PTSD, and also well know to the ANtieku crew how much Hide meant to him(Kaneki). So I'm assuming that Yomo wanted Kaneki to have as much time as possible left with his friend, seeing as Hide is dead or dyeing.(Sorry to those who were in denial) It is also apparent throughout both manga and anime that Yomo feels fatherly towards Kaneki, so he may have understood that in times like these, leave him alone. I do agree with lentinant however, he definitely  wants to protect Touka, though his last job was actually the manager's last orders: If I fall, burn Antieku so that none may trace it back to you. Basically the manager had Yomo get rid of the evidence that there were ghouls at Antieku. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In *Root A*, there's a scene where Hide walking down a street dying, but not yet dead as you can catch a glimpse of him smiling when Kaneki checking on him. Likely, Kaneki went to the CCG and gave up his life for Hide's medical treatment.

Answer (score 0):

In the anime Hide gets shot. He finds Kaneki outside injured and brings him to the cafe. When Kaneki wakes up Hide and him have a talk just about regular things. Hide then falls to the ground after bleeding, but then smiles and looks up to him. The cafe starts to burn down and they escape. Kaneki then takes him and brings him to where most of the police/ ghoul investigators are and lays him on the ground. After that it looks one of the ghoul investigators (Arima) is going to try to fight him. Its clear in anime that Kaneki doesn't eat Hide, and gets killed by Arima. Thats all I remember but hopefully it helps!